# How to get a list of running services in Android internet

Tags: android

I can successfully get the list of running processes 
but i want to get List all applications that use the Internet and send and receive data in the background...
May guide me? How do I get the applications that use the Internet?

Answer (score 2):

The closest you could get would be to use `PackageManager` to get a list of all packages (or those which have your list of running processes) and get the `PackageInfo` for each then examine the `requestedPermissions` array to find the `INTERNET` permission.